# How do you use indexers with array of objects?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, indexer

**How can we use indexers if we are using array of objects???**

For a single object:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MYInd mi = new MYInd();
    mi[1] = 10;
    Console.WriteLine(mi[1]);
    mi[2, 10] = 100;
    Console.WriteLine(mi[2]);

    Console.WriteLine(mi[3, 10]);
```

**What should be done for array of objects?**

```
MYInd[] mir = new MYInd[3];
```

How can we use each object and the indexer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options, if you want to iterate you do

```
foreach(MYInd mi in mir)
    Console.WriteLine(mi[3, 10]);
```

If you want to pick out a specific `MYInd` from the array you can do it in one step

```
Console.WriteLine(mir[1][3, 10]); // [1] picks out one object from the array
```

or in two steps

```
MYInd mi = mir[1]; // pick out one object from the array
Console.WriteLine(mi[3, 10]);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But i tried this and its giving me an exception. Exception :Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @Thomas, it's likely that you initialized the array (with the `new` keyword you wrote in your question) but not the objects themselves. Try `for(int i = 0 ; i < mir.Length ; i++) mir[i] = new MYInd();` after you create the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
mir[0][1, 2]
```

But you can imagine it as:

```
(mir[0])[1, 2]
```

The brackets aren't necessary because the [ operator is parsed left to right (like (1 + 2) + 3 == 1 + 2 + 3. I think it's called left-associativity, but I'm not sure sure :-) )

Remember that you have to initialize BOTH the array and the elements:

```
var mir = new MyInd[5];
for (int i = 0; i < mir.Length; i++) 
{
    mir[i] = new MyInd();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But i tried this and its giving me an exception. Exception :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You must initialize the array AND the array elements. var mir = new MyInd[5]; for (int i = 0; i < mir.Length; i++) mir[i] = new MyInd();